# Setting 'ball and stick' as default for new molecules in pymol

Tags: python, bioinformatics, chemistry, pymol, cheminformatics

I would like to have new molecules imported in pymol to be preset as 'ball and stick'.
I cannot find a way to make this a default setting, preferably in the pymol.rc.

In the command line,

```
preset.ball_and_stick(selection='all', mode=1)
```

is what gets the job done.

However, since the command relies on a selection, it has no effect in the pymol.rc, because it is loaded before any imports.

Also

```
set stick_ball, on
```

has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

wasnt able to find the setting either, only ways I could figure out are at

`script` or `plugin` level.

For the `script` option:

```
from pymol import cmd

def show_lines():

    cmd.hide('all')

    cmd.set('stick_ball' , 'on')
                    
    cmd.set('stick_ball_ratio' , '1.5')
    
    cmd.show('sticks' , 'all')

cmd.extend("show_lines", show_lines)
```

you need to run the `script` from the File Menu (maybe run it at startup ?? from `pymol.rc` or as arg ). Problem is that what it does is just adds a new pymol command `show_lines` that hides all the object loaded as **cartoons** and show them as **`sticks`**.

For the `plugin` one , you need to add a folder in your `plugin_installation_folder` that contains the below `__init__.py` file, and enable the script at startup from the **Plugin/Plugin Manager** Menu :

```
'''
PyMOL .............................. Plugin

'''
from pymol import cmd

from pymol.Qt import QtWidgets 


def getLoadFileNameWithExt(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Return a file name, append extension from filter if no extension provided.
    """

    fname, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(*args, **kwargs)

    if not fname:
        return ''

    return fname

def __init_plugin__(app=None):
    '''
    Add an entry to the PyMOL "Plugin" menu
    '''
    from pymol.plugins import addmenuitemqt
    
    addmenuitemqt('Load_Lines', run_plugin_gui)


#### ATTENZIONE A GLOBAL DIALOG SUPER NECESSARIO ############
# global reference to avoid garbage collection of our dialog
dialog = None

def run_plugin_gui():
    '''
    Open our custom dialog
    '''
    global dialog

    if dialog is None:
        dialog = make_dialog()

    dialog.show()

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.resize(400,400)
    
        self.Winlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.setLayout(self.Winlayout)
        
        self.button_browse = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Load pdb as Sticks')
        
        self.Winlayout.addWidget(self.button_browse)
    
        self.button_browse.clicked.connect(self.browse_filename)
        
    def browse_filename(self):
        
        self.loaded =  cmd.get_names(type = 'objects', enabled_only = 0)
        
        print('loaded objects : \n', self.loaded)
        
        self.filename = getLoadFileNameWithExt(
            self, 'Load ...', filter='PDB File (*.pdb)')
        
        if self.filename:
            print(self.filename)
            
            cmd.load(self.filename)
            
            self.loaded_after = cmd.get_names(type = 'objects', enabled_only = 0)
            
            for i in self.loaded_after:
                
                if i not in self.loaded:

                    cmd.set('stick_ball' , 'on')
                    
                    cmd.set('stick_ball_ratio' , '1.5')
                    
                    cmd.hide('cartoon' , i)
                    
                    cmd.show('sticks' , i )

def make_dialog():

    dialog = Window()
    
    return dialog
```

Running the `Plugin` will open a window:

[image]

pressing the button will open a load_dialog (for just.pdb , but that could be altered) , before loading the new object the plugin-script keeps track of the already loaded objects, and then after loading the new one , it only hide the cartoons and shows sticks for this one, need to figure out how to select multiple pdb for loading as in the pymol **File/Open** Menu , but thats another question.

**EDITED**

code to be changed to load multiple **.pdb**s at once:

`fname, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(*args, **kwargs)`

changes in :
`fname, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(*args, **kwargs)`  just one `s` more;

and :

```
...

if self.filename:
            print(self.filename)
            
            cmd.load(self.filename)
            
            self.loaded_after = cmd.get_names(type = 'objects', enabled_only = 0)
            
            for i in self.loaded_after:
                
                if i not in self.loaded:
                    

.....
```

changed in :

```
...
for filez in self.filename:

                print(filez)
                
                cmd.load(filez)
                
        self.loaded_after = cmd.get_names(type = 'objects', enabled_only = 0)
                
        for i in self.loaded_after:
                    
            if i not in self.loaded:
                        

...
```

You can play with:

```
cmd.set('stick_ball' , 'on')
                    
cmd.set('stick_ball_ratio' , '1.5')
```

for the representation that suits you better see: https://pymol.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=setting:stick and other googling resources